# "without any thing" or "with nothing"

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions, difference

How do the below sentences sound to you? Is there any difference?

1. > Stool is a seat having four legs with nothing to support your back.
2. > Stool is a seat having four legs without anything to support your back.
3. > Stool is a seat having four legs but with nothing to support your back.
4. > Stool is a seat having four legs and without anything to support your back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've just illustrated one of the beauties and perils of English. There are multiple ways to phrase nearly anything. Aside from some subtle punctuation issues relating to the conjunctions and disjunctions, there's nothing egregious about any of your alternatives.

I'd probably offer this alternative:

> "A stool is a seat having four legs, but nothing to support your
>   back."

Comment: Thus, can we think  "with nothing" is equal to "without" -"without anything"? In general, I mean

Comment: In the general sense, yes.

Comment: My pleasure and privilege to help!